Javafx Intellisense not working in vscode java project with no build tools
I had installed the Extension Pack for Java in VSCode and it works well while compiling a simple Java code, Intellisense is able to read and show descriptions and info about native Java classes and stuff when I hover them with the cursor. I can also compile and run a simple JavaFX program when using no build tools (added libraries from the official web, modified classpath in launch.json and all of that) but in this case Intellisense simply outputs information about class names/packages/parameteres but it doesn't show a description of the object (as IntelliJ does), and I cannot guide myself in the program. Am I forced to use Gradle or Maven to solve this or is there a way of fixing it without build tools? (PD: I don't really know if it works with build tools... I only want to make shure I can fix this without them)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I basically have this same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936428/code-intellisense-is-not-working-to-javafx-library-in-vscode) but instead of Gradle, I use no build tools

I think the answer of this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625811/how-to-add-javafx-javadocs-to-vscode-when-not-using-build-tools
